# How to disallow combobox to select unregistered item?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I would like to know if there is a combobox option to prevent selection of items not contained by the combobox of if I had to filter by myself.

As we can see in the following example, index of selected item is "-1"
Is there a way to prevent this before doing it ?

I mean, I know how to do it with code, i would like to know if it's possible to activate a combobox option to filter instead

Edit 1: registered items are "1","2","3","4"

The expected result with "xyz" (for me) should be: no selection at all because "xyz" is not a combobox item

Edit 2: Does the combox have a method to forbid (we could imagine to enable/disable a Combobox strict mode ...) adding an item that is not in the item list ?

```
package fr.meteo.pacome.adm;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Maintest extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 450, 250);
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1","2","3","4");
    ComboBox<String> emailComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(list);
    
    
    emailComboBox.getSelectionModel().select("notinlistChoice");

    System.out.println(emailComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
    
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setVgap(4);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    grid.add(new Label("To: "), 0, 0);
    grid.add(emailComboBox, 1, 0);
    
    
    Group root = (Group) scene.getRoot();
    root.getChildren().add(grid);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

  }
}
```

Comment: You could probably use a [`FilteredList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html). But I am not sure I understand the question.  What is a unregistered  item? What do you mean by disallow?  Do you want the item to not display in the combo box if disallowed or display and be grayed out and unselectable?  Can the items allowed or disallowed be changed dynamically?  What happens to the selection if a selected item is disallowed? You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. The combo box is allowed to have selected items that are not in the items list to support editable combo boxes (where the user might type in an item not in the list and commit its value). If the combo box is not editable, then the only way the combo box can have a selected item that is not in the list is if you explicitly write code that calls `setSelectedItem(…)` with an item not in the list. If you want to prevent that happening, just don’t write code that does that.

Comment: ok thanks , so the combox box doesn't have a strict mode ?

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox can't do this. You must build something by yourself.

Usable snippets:

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()
```

**What you can try:**

Set the value of the ComboBox to null, maybe this will help you.

Create your own ComboBox which can do this.
Create a class MyComboBox which extends from ComboBox, add needed methods and that's it!